# Nginx: add_before_body .php

Tags: php, nginx

Im trying to use a .PHP file in the function "add_before_body". I have used .HTML and it includes, however when I use .PHP it say "no input file specified".

I have checked the file directory and it's in there?

```
add_before_body \subsites\dropletlocal\library\global\func-global.class.php;
```